# How to to disable the send button if my fields are not filled using a textwatcher?

Tags: android, textwatcher

I'm having a hard time figuring out a solution to this situation. I need assistance, I am trying to disable the send button if my fields are not filled using a textwatcher. Here is part of the code:

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView shoppinglist, fullname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        fullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        shoppinglist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shoppinglist);

    public void send(View v) {

        new Send().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using TextView for taking input?  should use EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and use EditText, TextView is not inputable:

`editText1.addTextChangedListener(this);
imageButton.setEnable(false);`

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.toString().equals("")) {
        imageButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        imageButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Actually you don't need to use the textwatcher for disabling send button. All you could do is disable the send button in onCreate method within an if loop.**

> ***Note: Use EditText instead of TextView for taking inputs from user.***

```
    public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText shoppinglist, fullname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
    fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttsave);
    shoppinglist = findViewById(R.id.shoppinglist);
    final String username = fullname.getText().toString();
        final String shopList = shoppinglist.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)&&TextUtils.isEmpty(shopList)) {
            fullname.setError("Please enter your fullname");
            shoppinglist.setError("Please select shopping list");
            button1.setEnabled(false);
        }
       else {
       button1.setEnabled(true);
       }


//close onCreate here
}

public void send(View v) {
 // it is not possible to enable the send button here because you are already 
// executing the send method. So it should have already been enabled.       
        new Send().execute();
    }
```

> **Again, if there is a necessity of using the textwatcher then do this:**

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {

    EditText shoppinglist, fullname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttsave);
        shoppinglist = findViewById(R.id.shoppinglist);
        fullname.addTextChangedListener(this);
        shoppinglist.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    final String username = fullname.getText().toString();
            final String shopList = shoppinglist.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)&&TextUtils.isEmpty(shopList)) {
                fullname.setError("Please enter your fullname");
                shoppinglist.setError("Please select shopping list");
                button1.setEnabled(false);
            }
           else {
           button1.setEnabled(true);
           }
    }

    public void send(View v) {
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        new Send().execute();
    }
```

Hope this helps. Reply in comment if you still have any doubts.

Comment: I'm sorry button1 isn't use for anything I added that part in as a mistake.

Comment: have you got the solution? instead of button1 you can modify it with your button. Also use textwatcher only if necessary.

Comment: public void send (View view)........the send button is the button i want to disable not the button1

Comment: should it be v.setEnabled(false)

Comment: yeah whatever you have given at the time of declaration.